# How to get an 'and' query working with sails-mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, sails.js

I've got one query that work within a mongo shell

```
db.getCollection('insights').find({$and:[{author:/jim/i}]})
```

returns 2 records.

The 'or' code calling waterline/sailsjs-mongo

```
db('insights').find({
    or: [
        {or: [ {author: new RegExp( ".*"+"jim"+".*", 'i' )} ] }
    ]
    }).limit(req.params.limit).skip(req.params.offset).exec(function (err, insights) { ... }
```

returns 2 records as expected.

If I change the 'or' to an 'and'

```
db('insights').find({
    or: [
        {and: [ {author: new RegExp( ".*"+"jim"+".*", 'i' )} ] }
    ]
    }).limit(req.params.limit).skip(req.params.offset).exec(function (err, insights) { ... }
```

I get 0 records which is not expected. It should return 2 records.

I wrote some code using the native mongodb javascript client.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
  test = require('assert');
// Connection url
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/infosystem';
// Connect using MongoClient
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  // Create a collection we want to drop later
  var col = db.collection('insights');
  // Show that duplicate records got dropped
  col.find({$and:[{author: new RegExp('.*Jim.*','i')}]}).toArray(function(err, items) {
    test.equal(null, err);
    test.equal(2, items.length);
    db.close();
  });
});
```

Which when run throws no assertions.

```
 node test_insights.js
```

mongodb is version 3.2.9, sails-mongodb and waterline is version "0.12.1"

What is the correct way to call a mongodb $and query within sails-mongodb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#and

> $and performs a logical AND operation on an array of two or more
>   expressions (e.g. expression1, expression2, etc.) and selects the
>   documents that satisfy all the expressions in the array. The $and
>   operator uses short-circuit evaluation. If the first expression (e.g.
>   expression1) evaluates to false, MongoDB will not evaluate the
>   remaining expressions.

So in your case it does not even make sense to use the AND operator because you also can use an implicit AND, like

```
db.getCollection('insights').find({author:/jim/i})
```

To come to your actual problem. I cannot reproduce this issue using native mongodb. In shell:

```
db.collection.insert({name:'Foo', age:28})
db.collection.insert({name:'Bar', age:32})

db.collection.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57ca84c374f2776cc983ad9e"), "name" : "Foo", "age" : 28 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57ca84cd74f2776cc983ad9f"), "name" : "Bar", "age" : 32 }

db.collection.find({$and:[{name:new RegExp('.*Fo.*','i')}]})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57ca84c374f2776cc983ad9e"), "name" : "Foo", "age" : 28 }

> db.collection.find({$or:[{$or:[{name:new RegExp('.*Fo.*','i')}]}]})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57ca84c374f2776cc983ad9e"), "name" : "Foo", "age" : 28 }

> db.collection.find({$or:[{$and:[{name:new RegExp('.*Fo.*','i')}]}]})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57ca84c374f2776cc983ad9e"), "name" : "Foo", "age" : 28 }
```

I get the expected result. However when I try to use waterline queries with nested and/or I see the same problem that you describe. Let's have a look at following native query:

```
db.collection.find({$or:[{$and:[{name:'Foo'}, {age:28}]}, {name:'Bar'}]})
```

which correctly returns:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57ca84c374f2776cc983ad9e"), "name" : "Foo", "age" : 28 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57ca84cd74f2776cc983ad9f"), "name" : "Bar", "age" : 32 }
```

Now lets create the same query in waterline:

```
Test.find({
    or: [
        {and: [{name:'Foo'},{age:28}]},
        {name: 'Bar'}
    ]
})
```

this returns `[]`. The relevant code responsible for the and/or query can be found here: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/blob/master/lib/query/index.js#L132

I am sure the nesting of and/or operators is simply not supported by [sails-mongo](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo) but I was not able to find any evidence. You could file a feature request on their github page.

As a workaround you can use the native underlaying mongodb adapter to create your queries. As a downside your code will not be database agnostic.

Comment: Thanks artworkad. I think using the native mongodb client or the sails-mongo native underlaying mongodb adapter is the way to go.

Comment: I ended up dropping back to the native MongoDB client for this.